# PowerShell Получение имени пользователя по physicalDeliveryOfficeName

Tags: powershell

Необходимо получить список пользователей (SamAccountName) используя офис (physicalDeliveryOfficeName)
Для одного пользователя использовал:
`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=273)" | select SamAccountName`

Возможно *physicalDeliveryOfficeName=273* получать из *.csv или *.txt файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен в работоспособности и оптимальности тк нет под рукой AD, но можно попробовать

```
$Result = @()
$Deliveryoffice = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Deliveryoffice.txt'
foreach ($Office in $DeliveryOffice){
   $Result += (Get-ADUser -Filter "physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq $Office").SamAccountName  
} 
Write-Output $Result
```

Comment: Говорит что фильтр пустой, предпологаю ошибка тут ```(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=$_)``` или в txt файле. У Вас скорее всего ночь. Пробую пока сам разобраться

Comment: Изменил 3ю строку на такую:
```$Result += $Deliveryoffice | Get-ADUser -F {physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq '$_'} | select SamAccountName```

Теперь говорит:
Get-ADUser : Не удается привязать объект ввода к любым параметрам команды, так как команда не принимает входные данные конвейера, либо входные данные и их свойства не со
впадают с любыми из параметров, принимающих входные данные конвейера.
C:\1\id-to-name.ps1:3 знак:30

Comment: `$Result = '';
$Deliveryoffice = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Deliveryoffice.txt';
foreach ($Office in $DeliveryOffice){
    $Result += (Get-ADUser -Filter "physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq $Office").SamAccountName
}
Write-Output $Result;`

Comment: единственная проблема - выводит все имена пользователей в одну строку

Comment: Ок, тогда можно объявить $Result = @()  как массив. Тогда должен выдавать результат построчно

Comment: я сам не додумался, все гоолову ломал как перенос строки добавить в итоге ошибки тоннами ловил
Спасибо